# RVM cannot install ree

Tags: ruby, rvm

When trying to install ree with rvm, I get the following error:

```
Error running 'env CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib...
please read /Users/me/.rvm/log/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/install.log
There has been an error while trying to run the ree installer. Halting the installation.
```

The install.log says:

```
cc1: error: /opt/local/include: Permission denied
```

There is no `/opt/local/include`.  I can install other rubies, just not ree.

Comment: the path `/opt/local/include` is not listed as part of the command, please update rvm `rvm get head` and add full output of: `rvm install --debug ree`

Comment: fixed this by symlinking /opt/local to /usr/local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following to install ree successfully in MAC.

```
brew install libksba autoconf automake apple-gcc42

rvm autolibs enable

CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm reinstall ree-1.8.7-2011.03
```

Answer (score 1):

CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install ree-1.8.7-2012.02 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`